# Comparing two strings for "greater than '0' ..and NULL"

Tags: java, string-comparison, comparison-operators

I am trying to dig my way through the strict Java methods and operators, but now, trying to 'translate' a piece of PHP code to Java (Android), I'm kinda stuck.

In PHP:

```
if ($row['price']>'0'){
  (.. do something if price is defined - and higher than zero ..)
}
```

The problem is that $row['price'] may be empty (in Java: null?) or contain '0' (zero).
But how can I code that in Java in a smart and not too complicated way?

Comment: Note: There's a difference between an empty string and a null reference.

Comment: Use relevant tags. I retagged it for you.

Comment: have a look at the `compareTo()` method in the String class API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you got the price string in a variable price

```
String price = <get price somehow>;    
try {
    if (price != null && Integer.valueOf(price) > 0) {
        do something with price...
    }
} catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
}
```

Comment: Why you need to convert price to Integer ?  the original version just comparing them as string.  so I guess you can simply go for price.compareTo("0") > 0.

Comment: compareTo comapres the strings lexicographically. This is not exactly what he's trying to do here as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this:

```
String price="somevalue";
int priceInt=Integer.valueOf(price);

try{
if( !price.equals("") && priceInt>0){

// if condition is true,do your thing here!

}
}catch (NullPointerException e){

//if price is null this part will be executed,in your case leave it blank
}
catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
}
```

Comment: Maybe we're talking different languages here? I'm using Java/Android, IsEmpty() is undefined for the String type and isn't it "&&" instead of "&"?

Comment: I didn't noticed the word 'Android'. I changed my answer. Moreover '&' differs from '&&'.Using '&&' will check only the first statement of the condition and if it's 'false', then the second statement will be ignored marking the whole condition as 'false'.